# How to fix NSInternalInconsistencyException?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, key-value-observing

I got NSInternalInconsistencyException error, whenever I trying to stream a song from url using AVPlayer. I make a global stream player on a struct so that my stream player can used globally.

here is my code to play a new song:

```
User.songPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: User.streamSongUrl!)!)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: User.songPlayer?.currentItem)
User.songPlayer?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: [], context: nil)

slidetimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.0, target: self, selector: "updateSlider", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
progressBar.hidden = true
progressTimerLabel.text = "PREVIEW"
progressMinTimeLabel.hidden = true
```

and here is the error log:

> 2015-10-20 10:00:41.453 joove[6466:141737] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7f88138c2490 of class AVPlayer was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:  (
>    Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7f8815e6ca70>
>   )'

How can I fix that? 
Give me any suggestion doesn't matter obj-c or swift

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear, and you've focussed very well on the code. You are adding a KVO observer to `User.songPlayer`, but later `User.songPlayer` is going out of existence, presumably because `User` is going out of existence, without your removing the observer. You must not let that happen.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. You added an observer to the `AVPlayer` but you are not removing the observer before the `AVPlayer` is deallocated.

Update your code to call `removeObserver` on `User.songPlayer` before the player gets deallocated.

Comment: I don't know when exactly User.songPlayer deallocated, can you give me more clear explanation?

Comment: You don't provide enough info for that. Perhaps you should add a `deinit` function for your `User` class. Or you should remove `self` as an observer when `self` is done with the player.

Comment: User is a struct so that i can't add deinit on User. I tried adding `User.songPlayer?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", context: nil)` before `User.songPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: User.streamSongUrl!)!)` and I got **2015-10-20 10:53:46.646 joove[8869:181039] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <joove.StreamPlayerVC 0x7f83798c1400> for the key path "status" from <AVPlayer 0x7f837d2cd1f0> because it is not registered as an observer.'**

Comment: You need to remove the observer just before `User.songPlayer` is deallocated, not before you create it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the common cause of `NSInternalInconsistencyException` is to not deregistering from KVO leading to unwanted crash as callback comes to an already released object.

Please ensure you remove your class observer from all notifications when deallocated. Something like this:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    User.songPlayer.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
}
```

Comment: This isn't the problem. It's the observer on the `AVPlayer`, not the `NSNotificationCenter` that is causing this crash. Though the code in this answer should also be added.

Comment: Yes you are right @rmaddy. In a rush I missed that line. Corrected my code now. Thank you!

Comment: This still isn't enough. This still doesn't deal with `User.songPlayer` being deallocated before `self` does which is the problem in the question.